# JavaScript onHightlight?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there any event listener for highlight event in HTML using JavaScript (sort of `onHighlight`)? Is it possible to get the text highlighted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) { // All browsers except IE <9
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) { // IE <9
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}
```

All browsers (except for IE <9) support `window.getSelection()`; IE <9 supports `document.selection.createRange().text`.

The function can be attached to `onmouseup`, if you wish to support mouse-based selection, or `onkeyup`, if you wish to support keyboard-based selection.

As Robby Shaw [mentions below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266065/javascript-onhightlight/7266159#7266159), QuirksMode's [**Introduction to Range**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) is fairly useful for understanding `Range` objects, which this code is based off.

Comment: that's cool ! how about using JS frameworks like jQuery / Prototype / Mootools ?

Comment: @Shivan It's simple enough that JS frameworks are unnecessary.

Comment: There is also selection via the "Select all" options in the browser's edit and context menus, which cannot be detected in some browsers (e.g. Firefox). IE and WebKit support a useful "selectionchange" event, which is attached to the document.

Answer (score 2):

No event handler for highlight, but you can write a function to check if anything is selected.

You can use document.getSelection() to check this.

If you want to highlight the specific text, you need to use range and document.selection to do it.

Please refer to http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html, it will help you to understand.